# Nano para Windows

Tags: windows, linha-de-comando

Alguém sabe como instalar o "nano" para usar no CMD do windows? Eu estou aprendendo a usar linha de comando para deixar de usar interface gráfica, mas estou tendo bastante dificuldade em configurar as ferramentas no windows.

Comment: O windows, tem o comando `edit`, caso seja 64bits, use `notepad`...

Comment: Eu baixei ele, mas não tenho ideia de como usar. E não achei nada na internet explicando.

Comment: Eu instalei por meio do [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Tem até o [VIM](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vim) para instalar.
Daí depois uso o prompt(cmd) ou powershell para utilizar.

Comment: Não é preciso _" instalar o "nano" para usar a linha de comando no windows"_. V. pode usar linha de comando no Windows a partir do CMD.EXE, cuja sintaxe é derivada a partir da sintaxe do COMMAND.COM (se v. não sabe o que é COMMAND.COM, não se preocupe, e não precisa procurar saber; é do tempo do DOS, **muito** antigo). A partir do WindowsServer2003 a MS disponibilizou a PowerShell, que tem sintaxe bem diferente. Já o nano é um editor de textos que funciona direto na janela de console, que permite editar os arquivos no próprio terminal, sem precisar de usar a interface gráfica.

Comment: Eu havia me expressado errado. O que e queria era usar Windows como se fosse Linux. hehe. Por indicação do @Sidon e depois de muita pesquisa, descobri como configurar o WSL. Hoje uso a versão 2, e isso tem funcionado muito bem.
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/wsl/install-win10#install-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Instale o Bash no windows:

As instruções aqui só servem para o Windows 10 a partir do Build 14316, se tiver usando um build anterior, atualize seu sistema.

1. Acesse as configurações do Windows 10, clicando no menu iniciar e
   depois em configurações;
2. Estando em configurações, clique na opção "Atualização e segurança";
3. Na tela seguinte clique em "Para desenvolvedores" e marque a opção
   "Modo desenvolvedor";
4. Confirme (botão "Sim") a ativação do modo desenvolvedor;
5. Vá na busca da barra de tarefas e digite "Ativar ou desativar
   recursos", e clique no resultado apresentado;
6. Na janela de recursos do Windows, assinale a opção "Windows Subsystem
   for Linux (Beta)";
7. Feche a janela que é apresentada e reinicie o computador;
8. Após reiniciar, vá na caixa de busca na barra de tarefas, digite:
   **bash** e clique no resultado apresentado.

Pronto, você está na melhor "linha de comando" disponível no mundo da computação. :-)

### Instale o nano:

Provavelmente o nano já vira instalado, se não, instale-o:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nano
```

Comment: Não precisa de instalar bash para rodar o Nano para Linux. Existe Nano para Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Você também pode instalar o Git CMD que vai funcionar da mesma forma.

Depois que instalar o Git CMD, vá a busca na barra de tarefas e digite "bash", irá aparecer a aplicação "Git Bash"...